# XCode iOS - Assertion Failure

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I’m just starting out to learn iOS development. I’m doing the “[Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1)” tutorial and I’m stuck on the section “Add Data”.

After setting the Table view to use ‘Dynamic Prototypes’, and setting the identifier to ‘ListPrototypeCell’, I added the method ‘cellForRowAtIndexPath’ but it’s crashing with these errors:

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
>
> 2014-08-10 13:35:50.519 ToDoList[8954:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:5439
>
> 2014-08-10 13:35:50.523 ToDoList[8954:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ListPrototypeCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>
> . 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I’ve been following the tutorial exactly and I can’t find the mistake. Can anyone suggest what I’m doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
**The code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    XYZToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the view controller to be the name of the class where you put this code?

Comment: Add "Exception breakpoint" to stop on the line causing this(which should be dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:). Check that you implemented that method in right controller and that in Storyboard table controller has correct class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell"];
```

For storyboards that's what you want.
Also follow it up if necessary with:

```
   if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell"];
    }
```

Edit: If instead, you want to continue using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, then in your controller's initialization you should use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`, as per the docs if you are not using a storyboard. Also the (cell == nil) part has become unnecessary in the latest Xcode versions.

Comment: If he's using a storyboard with dynamic table view cells, then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` should work just fine, and is actually the preferred way of doing it since it guarantees that a cell will be returned.

Comment: I don't think so. Also if he wants to use that version, he MUST register his class with `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. So that answer is correct.

Comment: Using a prototype cell, you do not need to call `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. It is essentially done for you.

Comment: Thanks @Rikkles, the code snippet works provided the if(cell == nil) is included. But can you explain why the code from Apple's tutorial doesn't work?? Does that mean I missed a step somewhere?

Comment: I think your problem is which version of Xcode you're using. In the latest version 6, your code should have run as-is. @DRBeardface is correct.

Comment: I just downloaded xcode last week but turns out to be only version 5.1.1, So I guess I'll update and check that out!

Comment: 6 is still in beta, so yes 5.1.1 is current